# Automated, selective copying/pasting cells based on multiple string values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in my Excel doc, Column A and Column B. Column A contains a wide variety of values, while Column B is blank. From the list in Column A, I want only certain values to copy in the adjacent cells in Column B. For example:

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysPlg.png)
[image]

In the above case, only Veg and Meat are copied into Column B, according to their locations in Column A.

I originally found VLOOKUP as a potential solution, but it only works with one lookup_value (would have to choose between Veg or Meat).

How can I achieve the same results, with multiple possible matches?

Comment: You'll need to give us some more info.  What's determining if they're copied to column B? What about their location says so?  What would you use a vlookup for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell B1 enter this formula:

```
=REPT(A1,OR(A1={"veg","meat"}))
```

Copy downward as far as needed.

Comment: I assume using `Or(A1={"veg","meat"}...` is the same as `Or(a1="veg",a1="meat"),...`?  Any particular advantages in using the array over two statements (aside from the fact that it is sexier)?  Just curious!

Comment: its mainly used for MANY different terms, so you dont haveto type `A1=` (expectically with `Sheet2!$A$243:$BA$366=` or something like that)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A conventional solution is to create a list of all the values that qualify as 'matches' (`Meat`, `Veg` and possibly many others), give it a Name (say `aList`) and then a formula such as:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,aList,1,0)),"",A1)
```

which does not change regardless of the length of `aList`.

Comment: Conventional and maintainable. This is how I'd do it.